# JNA Mapping to C 

Tags: c, jna

Hello every one I have following function in c and want to map in JNA what could be equivlent of this in JNA.

2.3. SI_Open

Description: Opens a device (using device number as returned by SI_GetNumDevices) and returns

a handle which will be used for subsequent accesses.

```
SI_STATUS SI_Open (DWORD DeviceNum, HANDLE *Handle)
```

Parameters:

1. DeviceNum—Device index. 0 for first device, 1 for 2nd, etc.
2. Handle—Pointer to a variable where the handle to the device will be stored.

Return Value:

SI_SUCCESS

SI_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

SI_INVALID_PARAMETER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SI_STATUS` is not a common type you should look at your header file for this answer I will take for granted that `SI_STATUS` type is `DWORD` (or 32 bit integer).

This would give the following mapping in jna

```
int SI_Open(int DeviceNum, PointerByReference handle)
```

Comment: yes You r right  by I have tried with both PointerByRefrence and IntByReference but didn't succeeded.currently I am reading port from registry but its not good Idea.help me please to sort out this problem of maping.

Comment: Well from the informations you gave to me, this is the correct mapping according to http://jna.java.net/#mapping. If you could provide me with additional documentation I might be able to point out the correct mapping. By the way, have you given a look at jna's "platform.jar" which provides a lot of native mapping (an handle mapping example)

Comment: if you see this http://www.silabs.com/support%20documents/technicaldocs/an144.pdf          Two functions CP210x_GetNumDevices()  and CP210x_GetProductString() works for me but I am unable to get the Handle in CP210x_Open()  bcz you can see all remaining functions depends upon Handle.So have a look at please I am stuck at this.

Comment: also here is more that are used to compare if function is success or not.                                                                                                      public static final int CP210x_SUCCESS = 0x00;
public static final int CP210x_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND=0xFF;
public static final int CP210x_INVALID_PARAMETER=0x02;

Comment: Well, I've read (almost) everything but I can't find where things start getting bad... Can you try this and give me the result : http://pastebin.com/0HdkUPXh

Comment: I tried like " int status=CLibraray.INSTANCE.CP210X_Open(devNo,prt);{ Systyem.out.print(status); Systyem.out.println(prt.gaetValue());} but it gives me status value 255 and prt.getValue() as null. where devNo is device No and prt is PointerByReference

Comment: Thank you very much eventually Open method got success.the problem was that when i attached device its shows the devNo one but according to specification first device should show zero.I don't know why it shows one either they have some mistake.But now I get the error 
Error in DeviceIoControl routine: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Well I think you  misunderstood what SI_GetNumDevices does : It tells you how much devices are availiable, not the device number. As there is only one device attached it gets number 0 and total device count returned by SI_GetNumDevices is 1